# Custom formatting for Gravity Forms entries / entry_detail page

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I've created a custom email notification for a Gravity Forms form but I was wondering if it is possible to use the same custom format that I have created to display the entry details from within Wordpress?

I have searched in SO and Google but no one seems to have the answer - they are mostly about how to show the entry data on the front-end.

I could just go to the entry_details.php file and modify it but I was wondering if there is a proper way of doing it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got in contact with Gravity Forms and they have advised me the following:

"I'm afraid the layout of the entry detail page is not customizable. The recommendation would be that you create your own custom page outside of Gravity Forms, and use the GFAPI to get the entries for display."

For now it looks like we can create an external page and format how we like but not the actual Entry Details page in the CMS.